# Search is not working correctly when data contains dash

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.10 and I am getting an issue with the search functionality.

If the column data contains a `-` it does not allow a search from anywhere with the text it only allows a left to right match.

For example I have `this is - test`.

I can search for: `this is`, `thi`, `th`, ... and it works ok and returns the record.

If however I try to search: `test`,`- test`, `-`, it does not return a match.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have been looking around on the net and cannot see to find anything.

Comment: It works for me, see https://jsfiddle.net/2hj6pmza/

Comment: yeah just noticed it is working now. Not sure what was happening something must have had a knock on effect